# What causes error message 0x800700EA with PowerShell Remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

The situation: I want to setup PowerShell remoting (it's working on my other 2 machines). 
I run:

```
winrm quickconfig
```

Result:

```
winrm : WSManFault
At line:1 char:1
+ winrm quickconfig
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WSManFault:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = More data is available. 
Error number:  -2147024662 0x800700EA
More data is available.
```

I am also wondering where the 'More data' can be found?

```
PS F:\powershell\Text\SEO> Enable-PSRemoting -Force
WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this computer.
Set-WSManQuickConfig : More data is available. 

At line:69 char:17
+                 Set-WSManQuickConfig -force
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

Comment: what is the output of Enable-PSRemoting –force ?
also verify winrm is started ( get-service winrm )

Comment: @Kayasax  Added output from Enable-PSRemoting -force

Comment: so winrm seems to be enabled ...try `dir WSMan:\localhost\shell` is allowremoteshellaccess = true ? and check the listeners `winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener`

Comment: Did you check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847850.aspx

Comment: AllowRemoteShellAccess  true

Comment: winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener (No listener on this machine, other machines have port 5985)

Comment: if you try to manualy add listener ? `winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP`. BTW what os is running  ?

Comment: You're welcome (i regulary got usefull infos from your site :) )